# Как определяется восклицательная интонация?

Tags: интонация

По интонации различаем восклицательные и невосклицательные предложения. По цели высказывания укажем предложения повествовательные, вопросительные и побудительные предложения.  Подробнее: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/vidyi-predlozheniy.html

**Это верно? А что такое восклицательная интонация? И где здесь вопросительная интонация?**

**Вопрос** — это восходящая интонация в конце предложения, выражающая идею незаконченности. **В повествовательных** предложениях интонация тоже повествовательная, нисходящая, то есть понижение тона, законченность сообщения.

**А при восклицании** мы повышаем тон, понижаем тон или что мы вообще делаем?

Попробовала поискать в Интернете, но нашла нечто странное https://studfiles.net/preview/1644536/page:5/

Вопрос остался открытым.

Answer (score 1):

Можно согласиться с утверждением из "странного" источника: мы именно **понижаем** тон на одном из ключевых слов (хотя и не всегда воскл. интонация предложения сводится только к этому). Это означает, что в начале такого слова тон высокий, а к концу (или к ударному слогу) он резко спадает. Аналогия с русскими интонациями часто приводится при объяснении китайских слоговых тонов. Здесь (в случае короткого слова) есть нечто похожее на 4-й тон, а при пояснении 2-го (восходящего) тона иногда приводят похожий по тональности пример недоуменного вопроса: "да?!".

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ. А Вы не могли бы объяснить это на таких примерах.  Как здесь красиво! - Да, здесь красиво. Чем отличаются предложения по интонации?  Ударение в обоих случаях на "красиво", а дальше?

Comment: Здесь в вопросительном варианте спадающую интонацию можно рассмотреть на протяжении всего предложения: первые два слова произносятся равномерным высоким тоном (первый "китайский"), а в последнем слове тон спадает к ударному слогу. В варианте утверждения спадающая интонация затрагивает слово "да" и ударный слог слова "красиво", в промежутке тон плавно нарастает.

Comment: Вообще-то по теории интонации текст делится на фразы, и изменение тона (повышение или понижение) происходит в каждой фразе один раз - на ударном слоге слова, обычно последнего. Там не говорится о плавном изменении тона внутри фразы. Но возможно, разные есть теории. В любом случае спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

А я с ходу нашла простое, тем и остроумное:

[Восклицательная...](http://yourspeech.ru/training/articulation/chto-takoe-intonaciya.html)

> ...интонация выше по тону, чем при повествовании, но ниже чем при
>   вопросе.

Исчо:

> Существует три особенности восклицательных предложений.
>
> Наиболее сложным вопросом в отношении восклицательных предложений
>   является проблема числа его центров - его мелодические характеристики
>   скорее диффузны.

**[Особенности восклицательных предложений](http://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/intonac/fr_int/fii.htm)**

> - Дугообразная фигура тона характеризует восклицательное предложение.
> - Крайне высокая средняя длительность и, более конкретно, длительность ударного слога - носителя оценки.
> - Третья характерная особенность восклицательных предложений - их относительно ровная и в целом повышенная громкость. Но среднюю
>     громкость они могут дать такую же, как, например, вопросительное
>     предложение с вопросительным словом (где средняя громкость высокая за
>     счет яркого по громкости начала).

(Все термины в цитате-гиперссылке кликабельны.)