# Будь уверен в себе(,) и ничего отнюдь не боись

Tags: запятые

В справочнике Лопатина написано, что, если у нас обе части предложения побудительные, мы не дожны ставить запятую перед *и*. Там, однако, нет прям такого примера, как, например, мой, т. е. такой, который внизу написан.

Будь уверен в себе(,) и ничего отнюдь не боись.

Правда, что запятая не нужна отнюдь?

Лопатин-с: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что вы даете ссылку на правила, в которых говорится о пунктуации в сложносочиненных предложениях, а представленное предложение является простым (сказуемые однородны, подлежащего нет, но оно подразумевается).

[Ты] ***Будь уверен** в себе **и** ничего отнюдь **не боись*** (= не бойся).

> **1.** Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами ***и, да*** (в значении ‘и’), ***да и***, запятая не ставится: *Часовой **дошёл** до противоположного угла **и повернул** обратно* (Ф.)...

*...будь джентльменом, будь уверен в себе **и** превосходи ожидания* (А. Шварценеггер).
*Будьте уверены в себе **и** не бойтесь выделяться из толпы* (из статьи).

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100)

Comment: Есть ли ссылка на правило, где указывается, что это однородные сказуемые. Ведь каждое отдельное предложение является односоставным определенно-личным предложением.

Comment: Каждое предложение имеет свой распространитель, а общего элемента нет, в том числе нет побудительной интонации. Это способствует разделению предложения и постановке запятой. Также обе части могут иметь логическое ударение и тогда произносятся с паузой.  Здесь нужно указание на источник с решением подобных задач.

Comment: А если такое предложение? *Петя, будь смелым(,) и, Вася, научись готовить сам себе гречу.*

Comment: @Sharon, странно, что вы не усматривает общую побудительную интонацию. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: То же у Лопатина.

Comment: Серж,  а как выглядит побудительная интонация, какая у нее модель? Обсуждали  здесь восклицательную интонацию, но и это я не поняла.  А без моделей как рассуждать об их особенностях https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448406/Как-определяется-восклицательная-интонация  Я думаю, что эту фразу можно произнести с восклицанием или с нейтральной интонацией.  Здесь восклицательного знака у автора  нет. Конечно, это призыв, и восклицание более уместно, но есть же обычные предложения, например: Петя, возьми лучше свою книгу и работай сАм.  А вот когда есть частица "пусть", то это уже общий элемент.

Comment: Вот определение: Побудительная интонация — это особый интонационный паттерн, который имеет сильное воздействие на слушателя и используется для передачи эмоционального или призывного оттенка высказывания. Ну и что с этим делать, как работать с таким определением? Но и общая интонация не гарантирует однозначное решение. Например: Ты встАнь сначала, и уж потОм отвечай! Здесь надо поставить два ударения, а это неизбежная пауза. Только нераспространенные предложения можно объединить общей интонацией, такие предложения и приводятся в правилах.