# Почему сложно решить вопрос о постановке запятой перед союзом И в односоставных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, и, ссп, интонация

Действительно, тема весьма **неопределенная** и вызывает много вопросов.  В справочниках **недостаточно сведений**,  особенно по некоторым видам предложений.

Это в первую очередь касается  **определенно-личных и обобщенно-личных** предложений. Там обычно мыслится один производитель, что задается 2-ым лицом. Можно ли их приравнивать к **однородным** членам (грамматическая тема)?  А если нельзя или это неизвестно, то можно ли ориентироваться  **на общий элемент** в ССП.

Много вопросов по побудительным, отрицательным и восклицательным **предложениям**. Там общим элементом является **интонация**, а это вещь ненадежная. Произношение таких предложений может быть разным, не менять же при этом пунктуацию.

Все эти вопросы возникают, например, при решении **таких задач** [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474962/Будь-уверен-в-себе-и-ничего-отнюдь-не-боись](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474962/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

**И как тут быть?**  Может, стоит решать эти задачи **по общему принципу** (с учетом структуры, семантики, интонации), а не по **частным** особенностям их грамматики?

Comment: Только вам сложно.