Голосуй(,) или проиграешь. Запятая перед союзом ИЛИ между определенно-личными предложениями
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE

Возможно, не все знают, что это определенно-личные предложения, но это действительно так. Только вот грамматическая форма в данном случае разная, сравнить: Иди и голосуй (повелит. наклонение. Выиграешь или проиграешь (изъяв. наклонение). Литневская, стр. 80.
В определённо-личных предложениях главный член выражен глаголом в форме 
1 и 2 лица единственного и множественного числа изъявительного 
наклонения (в настоящем и в будущем времени), и в повелительном 
наклонении; производитель действия определён и может быть назван 
личными местоимениями 1 и 2 лица я, ты, мы, вы.


Имеет ли значение разная форма сказуемых? Возможно, что да. Влияет ли восклицательный знак на запятую? Скорее всего, влияет, но по текстам из Национального корпуса однозначно не скажешь — есть разные варианты.

А что говорится в правилах Розенталя и ПАС? Там определенно-личные предложения не рассматриваются, хотя все остальные виды односоставных предложений расписаны.


Так как ж правильно и почему?
Тема на форуме

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА  SE
1. О ВОСКЛИЦАТЕЛЬНОЙ ИНТОНАЦИИ
Восклицательным можно сделать любое простое  нераспространение предложение (даже без структурных частиц), так как восклицательная интонация — это особое тональное построение фразы, вот здесь есть обсуждение: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448406/Как-определяется-восклицательная-интонация
Если взять ССП, то вопросительной может быть все предложение или только вторая часть, а вот восклицательным должно быть все предложение, поэтому правильны  две записи:
(1) ГолосУй, или проигрАешь. Нет восклицательного знака.
(2) Голосуй или проигрАешь!  Восклицательный знак.
2. КАК ДОКАЗАТЬ?
Попробуем распространить предложение, добавив бессоюзную связь. Голосуй или проигрАешь  —  такова ситуация в целом /  других возможностей нет. Теперь два сообщения объединены общей второй частью, и ударение  соответствующее. Таким образом, ИНТОНАЦИЯ может выполнять ту же связующую функцию, что и бессоюзная связь.
3. ОБ ОДНОРОДНЫХ СКАЗУЕМЫХ
В некоторых случаях определенно-личные предложения можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым. Для этого грамматическая форма относительно повелит. или изъявит. наклонения должна быть одинаковой: Оставайся или уходи. Остаешься или уходишь. Но: Голосуй, или проиграешь.
Почему так?
(1) В ПАС требование по одинаковой форме относится к безличным или неопределенно-личным предложениям.
(2) Сказуемые в определенно-личных предложениях имеют одно грамматическое лицо, то есть мыслится одинаковый производитель действия (это требование у Розенталя для неопределенно-личных предложений).
Соответственно, для  определенно-личных предложений всё аналогично. При одинаковой форме предложения приравниваются к однородным сказуемым и запятая не ставится. Но если формы разные, то для односоставных предложений требуется наличие связующего фактора в виде восклицательной интонации.
4. ВЫВОД
Таким образом, проект решения готов, можно пользоваться)  То есть на все почему есть ответ со ссылкой на правило, что нам и нужно.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
ПРАВИЛА (в них нет ни  одного определенно-личного предложения)
Также обратим внимание на дополнительные структурные элементы, которые характерны для названных предложений (частицы и др.) Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! – это односоставные инфинитивные предложения
Пункт 3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?

побудительные предложения: Подпустить врага и огонь дать по команде! (Фурм.) — объединяет побудительная интонация; Пусть кончится холод и наступит тепло! — объединяет побудительная частица; Да будет свято имя героя и память о нём сохранится в веках! — объединяет побудительная частица;

восклицательные предложения: Как он смешон и как глупы его выходки! — объединяет восклицательная интонация; Как часто мы собирались вместе и какие вели интересные беседы!; Сколько скрытого смысла в этих словах и какой отклик вызывают они у слушателей!;


